# Eclipse export .jar with referenced libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

I've added a few libraries to my project as external jars, one being HikariCP (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) however when I run my jar I'm given these errors

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

I've tried to bundle these libraries by exporting the project as a "Runnable Jar file" and ticked "Package required libraries into generated jar", however the same errors still persist.

I don't currently have my project set up with Maven, as I've never had the reason to use it (until now?) I've heard this is easy to accomplish via Maven however I was wondering if there's another workaround without it.

Comment: try 'Extract required...' - the first option.  Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running after including `.classpath` file in the jar file.
You can include the .classpath file from the `jardesc` in eclipse.

Comment: The .classpath file appears to already be exporting with the jar file

Comment: I have tried this, however I did what Christian Cerri suggested and used the first option. It seemed to work and I no longer get the errors, but it seems to have included a jar I didn't want, even after configuring the 'Order and Export' for the Java Build Path. Any idea how I can exclude certain libraries?

Comment: xDeeKay - I don't use runnable jars any more because they get too big and any little update requires a big upload.  Now, I just package a normal jar for my source code and use a libs directory, running with "java -cp myjar.jar:libs/* ...".  I find it's a lot quicker.  To exclude libs, just make sure they are not in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would go the lib directory route, however my program is for public use so I'd rather have everything packed into the jar itself, purely for convenience. The library I want excluded is only in my project as a Referenced Library, so I still need to reference things from it, just not have it packed into the exported jar.

Comment: Understand on the simplicity of a runnable jar for distribution - careful there are some warnings about redistribution rights.  On the referenced lib - I'm confused.  If your project needs it, you'll need it in your jar right? Not sure what you mean you need to reference it but don't want it "extracted" into your jar... then it won't work as a single runnable jar.

Answer (score 0):

Unpack libs. Next Alt-Enter => Java Build Path => Libraries =>
1. Remove packed library
2. Click "Add External Class Folder"
3. Select your folder with library(-es)
4. Click OK
5. Enjoy :)

Comment: When I try this the src and the rest of the packages in the folder are empty

Comment: @xDeeKay, Because you need compiled lib's. Otherwise - drop it into your src folder (Too late, yes?)